# BrowserRouter - how to access history? Change location in component or in action?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, browser-history

I use `BrowserRouter` in my `React/Redux` app, so I don't create `history` object nor pass it to `BrowserRouter`, as it handles its own history. At the moment, I mocked login functionality, and this is function in `Login` component (which calls `login` thunk in `authActions`):

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.authActions.login({
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        });
    };
```

`AuthActions` are mapped to component props:

```js
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        authActions: bindActionCreators(authActions, dispatch)
    }
}
```

And this is `login` thunk in `authActions`:

```js
export function login(userData) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        if(userData.email === 'test@test.com' && userData.password === 'pw'){
            sessionStorage.setLoggedUser(JSON.stringify(userData));
            dispatch(loginSuccess(userData));
            this.context.router.history.push('/');
        } else {
            dispatch(loginFail());
        }
    }
}
```

I get error that `context` is undefined, but after successful Login, app navigates to "/" route. I passed `context` as second parameter to `constructor` and `super` methods in `Login` component.

```js
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
```

Now, my question is. What is the best place to do location changes? Component itself, or in actions (thunks)? I mention thunks for purpose, as I will change code and have some async calls to backend. How to access `history` object when using `BrowserRouter, in both component and actions bound to it?

Comment: use withRouter from react-router-dom. ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477910/redirect-react-router-from-context-provider/51478324#51478324

Comment: In order to access history in actions, you either need to pass it from the component while dispatching action or you can create a history object, Please Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514773/use-history-push-in-action-creator-with-react-router-v4/48514877?noredirect=1#comment89952323_48514877 for more details

Comment: Also accessing router from context isn't supported in react-router-v4, you can have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is: change location in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

you have there some `props` to compare, make some actions etc...

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount.

even better when you create HOC for managing location changes

**UPDATE**

first, **NO** change location in `render` func, this will generate error.

there any many many soloutins, based on your app structure...
another solution is use 'componentWillReceiveProps'

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState){
  if(nextProps.isLoggedIn===true&&this.props.isLoggedIn===false){
    nextProps.history.push('path_for_logged_in')
  }
}
```

for access history in props, you need wrap your component with `withRouter` HOC

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'


withRouter(YourComponent)
```

Comment: Can't change location in `componentDidMount` because location should be changed immediatelly after correct credentials on Login, in other words after dispatching `successful login` action. So it should be in action(thunk) or in component's login function, which is called on click. So lifecycle hook is not solution.